# install problem: Cmake error : include could not find load file: yarpl-exports.cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to install fbthrift for fb-python.

I followed the guides in 
https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift and installed  the dependencies needed.

but I got this error when running

```
    cmake ..
```

in cmd:

```
-- Found folly: /usr/local
CMake Error at /home/xian/rsocket-cpp/build/yarpl/yarpl-config.cmake:31 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /home/xian/lib/cmake/yarpl/yarpl-exports.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:107 (find_package)


-- Found YARPL: /home/xian
-- Could NOT find rsocket (missing: rsocket_DIR)
-- Found fizz: /usr/local
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:110 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fmt" with any of
  the following names:

    fmtConfig.cmake
    fmt-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "fmt" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "fmt_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "fmt" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I tried to build the path doing:

```
sudo cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/xian/rsocket-cpp/build/yarpl/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake
```

but it doesn't work.

yarpl-exports.cmake is in

```
/home/xian/rsocket-cpp/build/yarpl/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake/yarpl
```

and I'm pretty sure I have installed rsocket-cpp.

what should I do?

Comment: "I'm pretty sure I have installed rsocket-cpp" - But the directory `/home/xian/rsocket-cpp/build/yarpl/CMakeFiles/Export/lib/cmake` which you assign to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` looks like **build directory**, not an *installation* one. You need to **install** the package for make `find_package` to work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for replying. You mean I didn't install rsocket-cpp successfully?
But I followed the instructions in https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-cpp and everything looks fine.

Comment: Instructions describe "*Building* and running tests", not **installation**. Installation is performed with `make install`. If you do not want to install into system directory, you may specify custom directory with `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install-dir>` parameter for `cmake`. The same `<install-dir>` you need to pass as a value for `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when configure your project which uses rsocket-cpp.

Comment: I had the same problem. I went to ~/rsocket/build and run a 'sudo make install'. after that, the issue was resolved. Thanks ! @Tsyvarev

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git clone https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
cd fmt
cmake CMakeLists.txt
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried install the dependencies fbthrift needs again with make install and another Cmake error happened. The error exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669530/cmake-is-not-able-for-find-python-six-library

Comment: Yes that was posted by me.... I was stuck up on that issue for about two weeks. Please let me know when you find solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `libfmt-dev` package ...

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

$ sudo apt-get install libfmt-dev
$ cmake .
-- Configuring done
```