# Cmake is not able for find python-six library

Tags: makefile, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, thrift

I'm trying to install Fbthrift, But I am getting this error:

```
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   context
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   system
--   thread
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Found folly: /usr/local
-- Found YARPL: /usr/local
-- Found rsocket: /usr/local
-- Found fizz: /usr/local
-- Found wangle: /usr/local
-- Found Zstd: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so  
-- ZLIB: /usr/include
-- Found Zstd: /usr/local/lib/libzstd.so  
-- ZSTD: /usr/local/include
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:144 (find_package):
```

> By not providing "Findpython-six.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
>   project
>         has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
>         "python-six", but CMake did not find one.
>
> ```
>   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "python-six" with
>   any of the following names:
>
>     python-sixConfig.cmake
>     python-six-config.cmake
>
>   Add the installation prefix of "python-six" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "python-six_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "python-six" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
>   been installed.
> ```

```
-- Python dependencies not found, will not build thrift/lib/py
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sarath/lib/fbthrift/_build
```

I have installed all dependencies as mentioned in official [FbThrift](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift) page 
Also I have installed cuda 8.0 and cuDNN 5.0 along with Torch 7 and its dependencies.
If I ignore this error and proceed to [THPP](https://github.com/facebookarchive/thpp) installation, It shows **THRIFT_LIBRARY missing** and aborts installation. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has been solved by installing all dependencies in Ubuntu 14.02 LTS.

Comment: Hi. I am running into the same issue. Can you be more specific about the list of steps you've performed to install python-six?

Comment: I have changed OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 14.02. The issue has been resolved